# A way to switch amazon cognito roles

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using aws-ios-sdk with objective-c and have set up Amazon cognito to use unauthenticated access and authenticated access. The authenticated access is using custom developer identity.

The provider name in custom identity is:

```
com.test.developerProvider
```

In GetOpenIdForDeveloperCredentials I set:

```
com.test.developerProvider = uniqueUser;
```

The identityPool has role permissions for auth and unauth like so:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "identityInfo"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated or unauthenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I switch the role from Unauth to Auth? I don't care if it is in Lambda or some other way using ios.

Need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. The role gets changed from unauth to auth when you have a login token included in a request to get credentials. Are you saying that is not happening? You can confirm this by looking at the identity in the console's identity browser for your identity pool, if it has no logins tokens linked then that mean the token isn't getting sent to Cognito.

Comment: Yes it is working finally. The map wasn't set up correctly since I was using Developer Identities. I still need to figure out how to keep the user logged in for weeks though like other apps do.